# How can I replace the Nth instance of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to dynamically add an active class to a shortcode in wordpress based on the active number set in it's parent shortcode.

The parent looks like this:

```
$active = 3;
$output .= "\n\t\t".wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content);
```

The $content variable can technically consist of anything in between the shortcodes tags, but specifically, should include more child shortcodes (it's a tabs shortcode so the parent is tabs and the children are tab).

What I need to do is parse `$content` and replace the Nth (`$active` variable) instance of `[vc_tab` with `[vc_tab active="true"`

I realize there are better ways to design the shortcode to compensate for this but I am limited in what I can do because I am modifying Visual Composer to use Bootstrap tabs instead of jQuery and Bootstrap tabs need the active class on both the `<li>` and the `<div class="tab-pane">` elements but I don't want the users to have to add an active number to the parent shortcode and an active true/false to the child as that will get confusing.

So far from googling I can only find replacing the first occurrence or all occurrences, not the Nth one.

Temporarily I am using jQuery to make the appropriate `<div>` active but it results in an undesirable FOUC where there is no pane visible on load and then one pops into place when the jQuery runs.

```
$('.tabs-wrap').each(function(){
  var activeTab = $(this).find('.tabbed li.active a').attr('href');
  $(this).find(activeTab).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, and got me thinking *if* you really need a regex to do this.

My conclusion is that I don't believe you do. All you need to do is find the occurrence of the `Nth` `$needle`, and replace it with your replacement. This can be achieved through some simple string manipulation, as follows:

1. Define some variables. Your input string, your `$active` index, the `$needle` that we are looking for, and the `$replace`ment that we will replace the `Nth` match with.

   ```
   $string  = "[vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab";
   $active  = 3;
   $needle  = "[vc_tab";
   $replace = '[vc_tab active="true"';
   ```
2. Now, we need to make sure that there are enough `$needle`s in the `$string`, otherwise we can't do this replacement.

   ```
   if( substr_count( $string, $needle) < $active) {
       throw new Exception("There aren't enough needles in the string to do this replacement");
   }
   ```
3. Now, we know we can do the replacement. So let's find the `$index` in the string where the `Nth` occurrence of `$needle` ends:

   ```
   $count = 0; $index = 0;
   while( $count++ < $active) {
       $index = strpos( $string, $needle, $index) + strlen( $needle);
   }
   ```
4. Now, `$index` is pointing here in the string:

   ```
   [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab
                          ^
                          Here
   ```

   We can now do some simple `substr()`'s to form the final string:

   ```
   $result = substr( $string, 0, $index - strlen( $needle)) . $replace . substr( $string, $index);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             Before the Nth match                                        After the Nth match
   ```

   So, we end up concatenating:

   - `[vc_tab [vc_tab`
   - `[vc_tab active="true"`
   - `[vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab`

This results in our [final output](http://viper-7.com/g7JP8w):

```
[vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab active="true" [vc_tab [vc_tab [vc_tab
```

Try it out in [the demo](http://viper-7.com/g7JP8w)!

Comment: Thanks, this is working great - except, instead of throwing an exception in the error checking, I simply set `$active = 1` (back to the default value)

Answer (score 3):

I 'm not familiar with the tools you mention so I can't say if there is a better way to achieve the end goal, but you can replace the Nth occurrence of something using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$active = 3;     // target occurrence
$occurrence = 0; // counter
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[vc_tab/',
    function ($matches) use(&$occurrence, $active) {
        return ++$occurrence != $active
            ? $matches[0]
            : '[vc_tab active="true"';
    },
    $output,
    $active
);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/K6YJql)**.

This works by replacing each occurrence with itself unless the occurrence counter is equal to the target number.

Note that I have passed `$active` as the maximum number of occurrences to replace in order to get free performance increase; this will cause `preg_replace_callback` to stop after `$active` occurrences have been replaced (we know that all occurrences after that will be replaced by themselves, so there's no point in going on).

Comment: thanks for the help. preg_replace_callback looks like a useful function to keep in mind, but this code didn't work with the real world $output, rather than debugging it, I used the string manipulation method below which may be more efficient than regex?

Comment: @tsdexter: I 'm not sure -- low-level manipulation would likely need to be optimized, but I wouldn't venture to guess (measure if it's important). Not sure why this would not work for you as the code reads pretty clean.

Comment: well now I'm curious so I'll have to figure it out.

Comment: Hmm, I must have messed something up when I was changing variable names - it is working as you wrote it. I did some microtiming on the 2 and the results favour string maninpulation. I tested 1) 3 tabs/short content - 2) 11 tabs/long content - and 3) 11 tabs/long content w/last tab as active, the results were: (s = string, p=preg)  1) s:0.013113021851s / p:0.025987625122s 2) s:0.015020370483s / p:0.057935714722s 3) s:0.016927719116s / p:0.042915344238s